# how can I make div have auto height according to content

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find the answer I want on SO.
I wanted to know how can I auto height a div without using float and  maintaining margin auto so the div can be centered.

My problem is that `#contentwrap` is not doing auto height according to how tall `#content` is.

With `#content` having a auto height according to content I want `#contentwrap` to also have auto height according to `#content` height.

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/23q79/)

CSS:

```
#contentwrapper {
    margin-left: 131px;
    margin-right: 131px;
}
#contentwrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 700px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1150px;
}
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="contentwrapper">
    <div id="contentwrap">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show an example.. post your code to a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I'm on my phone kinda hard to do jsfiddle lol @webkit this question was hard and it was simple

Comment: Remove `min-height` from `#contentwrap` and `margin-bottom: 70px;`  from `#content `

Comment: Tried that height becomes 0 @BindiyaPatoliya

Comment: Then add some content then only it takes height `auto`

Comment: your question is unclear, please try adding more explanation or image to explain your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply try to remove this:

1. Remove `min-height` from `#contentwrap`
2. Remove `margin-bottom: 70px;` from `#content`

Try this :

```
<div id="contentwrapper">
<div id="contentwrap">
    <div id="content">
    Vice twee irony pickled sriracha mumblecore, VHS beard +1. Shoreditch post-ironic retro, actually plaid roof party irony kogi lo-fi organic. <br />Vice twee irony pickled sriracha mumblecore, VHS beard +1. Shoreditch post-ironic retro, actually plaid roof party irony kogi lo-fi organic.
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<style>
#contentwrapper {
    margin-left: 131px;
    margin-right: 131px;
}
#contentwrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 1150px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove **min-height** from #contentwrap and add **display: inline-block;** for #contentwrapper

   ```
   #contentwrapper {
       margin-left: 131px;
       margin-right: 131px;
   }    
   #contentwrap {
       margin: 0 auto;
       position: relative;
       width: 1150px;
       display: inline-block;
   }    
   #content {
       margin: 0 auto;
       margin-bottom: 70px;
       position: relative;
   }
   ```

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/23q79/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You simply use javascript to get the view height and set that height to your element.
By simply using CSS that can't be done.